# DetailsView OnUpdating TextBox not returning new text ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a `DetailsView` and a `SqlDataSource` as below. The `NotesTB` and the `NameTB` are not null in the code behind but are not retaining the new values entered in. They are returning the old values binded originally. I have searched the internet and can not find the reason for this and it is perplexing me.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="PhotoDetailsDV" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="PhotoID"  DataSourceID="XXXXXXXXXX" OnDataBound="PhotoDetailsDV_DataBound" OnItemUpdating="PhotoDetailsDV_ItemUpdating1" >
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NotesTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="PhotoIdHF" Value='<%# Bind("PhotoID") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="NotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>            
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="XXXXX" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Notes], Photoid, [Name] FROM [XXXXXXXX] WHERE ([FileID] = @FileID)"  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [XXXXXXX] SET [Notes] = @Notes, [Name] = @Name WHERE [PhotoID] = @PhotoID">        
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FileID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhotoID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My code behind is as follows

```
protected void PhotoDetailsDV_ItemUpdating1(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox NameTB = (TextBox) PhotoDetailsDV.FindControl("NameTB");
        TextBox NotesTB = (TextBox) PhotoDetailsDV.FindControl("NotesTB");
        e.NewValues["Notes"] = NotesTB.Text;//here NotesTB.Text is "" even when something is entered or it is the old value
        e.NewValues["Name"] = NameTB.Text;//here NameTB.Text is "" even when something is entered or it is the old value
    }
```

Comment: can you post your backend bind codes? seems you did not include bind into !IsPostback

Comment: What do you mean by backend bind codes?

Comment: the code your bind data to your detailview, do you use a not is postback condition to make sure it will not re-bind the data after postback?

Comment: Good point. I forgot the !isPostback. I am at home now but I will fix that in the morning at work. If you make it an Answer I will accept it in the morning if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code your bind data to your detailview, do you use a not is postback condition to make sure it will not re-bind the data after postback?